# How to measure points scattering in a circle

Tags: complex-geometry, st.statistics

I have circles containing points (x,y). I would like to measure the scattering of the points within the circle.
For example, in the following picture, circle A will have a higher value since the points are much more scattered across the circle.

[image]

Notice that the circles have varying value - so we can have a circles with different radiuses.
For example in the following picture, although the points are the same - circle C will have a higher value because the points are scattered across the whole circle.

[image]

Do you know a measurement which I can use for such purpose?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't mean-square distance from the points' center of mass, divided by the radius of the circle, do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

There exists a variety of measures of uniformity of a point set. See, for example, [On assessing spatial uniformity of particle distributions...](https://www.bme.psu.edu/labs/Yang-lab/publications%20PDF/with%20Lizeng.pdf) for an overview, and a critical comparison when applied to real-world data.

There are two distinct classes of uniformity measures: *Quadrat-based* measures divide the region into a number of small grids, called quadrats, and count the number of points falling into each grid. *Distance-based* methods focus on the distances between points, such as those between nearest neighbors or between randomly selected locations.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your pictures, it should be sufficient to consider the root-mean-square distance $\rho$ of the points $\vec{x}_k$ from their center of mass $\vec{\mu}$, divided by the radius $R$ of the circle:
\begin{align}
\vec{\mu} &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\vec{x}_k, \\
\rho &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\left\lVert\vec{x}_k-\vec{\mu}\right\rVert^2\right)}, \\
S &=\frac{\rho}{R},
\end{align}
where $S$ is your measure of scattering within the circle.

Answer (score 0):

## Star discrepancy

The [star discrepancy](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarDiscrepancy.html) is usually used when thinking about random numbers and low discrepancy sequences, and seems to fit the bill for your task.